# Jeditable extra space around OK button and Textarea

Tags: jquery, jeditable

Using Jeditable to edit table cells. After clicking on any editable table cells it places extra space on  right side of OK button and on left side of textarea. This makes the table bigger and also looks ugly.:-)
Help me to remove the extra space. I also adjusted the textarea width and height but it doesn't affect that extra space at all.....:-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved....

```
width     : 40,
```

It depend upon how much width you want for Textbox.